# Docker container can't connect to outside Oracle server

Tags: networking, docker, oracle-linux

My co-worker and I have the same set up: M1 Macs, Docker Desktop, connected to the same VPN - when they download a fedora image, install telnet in the container, and connect to a remote server:

```
docker pull fedora
docker exec -it [container id] /bin/bash
root@[container]: dnf install telnet -y
root@[container]: telnet [domain] [port]
root@[container]: Trying [ip]...
```

they get:

`Connected to [domain name].`

When I follow the exact same steps, I get:

`telnet: connect to address [ip]: Connection timed out`

I thought this could be something with the network connection between the container and the local host system, but it seems like if we're following the exact same steps, there's something else breaking in the chain.

Comment: What is your networking config and what is the networking config of your coworker's system? What is the networking config OUTSIDE the systems, between your client computers and the target machine?

Comment: thx @music2myear - I was able to sort it out - when I ran `docker network prune` it erased quite a few unused network configurations, and I'm guessing somewhere in there was a blocking connection

Answer (score 0):

So this did turn out to be an issue with the docker network - running:

`docker network prune`

and then re-running the fedora commands allowed the connection go make it through.